# shuffle is not working in my 8 queen code error

Tags: python

```
import random
size = 8
grid = [['-' for m in range(size)] for n in range(size)]
insertPoints = size
random.shuffle(insertPoints)
for i in range(size):
     grid[i][insertPoints[i]] = "Q"
print(grid)
```

I have a python 3.4 and shuffle part is not working in this code, can someone please take a look at it

Comment: Please define "*not working*". What is it doing, and what are you expecting it to do? Are there any errors? If so, please show the **full text**.

Comment: @MattDMo this is the error that does come up when i try to run it         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Odisho\Downloads\8queens.py", line 5, in <module>
    random.shuffle(insertPoints)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 269, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing with those references to `insertPoints`. You define it as the same as `size`, so it is an integer. An integer can't be shuffled, nor can it be indexed as you do in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the thing is, when you use `random.shuffle()`, whatever you put I'm the parentheses has to be the variable name of a list, not an integer. That is why the error is 'int' object has no len(). This means that your variable which holds an integer does not have a length because that only applies to lists. If you made `insertPoints` into `insertPoints = []` and then followed by `insertPoints.append(size)`, that should work. Anyways, you can't really mix up a number can you? So your code would be:

```
import random
size = 8
grid = [['-' for m in range(size)] for n in range(size)]
insertpoints = size
#Delete random.shuffle(), replace with different command of choice such as
#importPoints = []
#importPoints.append(size)
for i in range(size):
     grid[i][insertPoints[i]] = "Q"
print(grid)
```

And whatever is needed to be added to the code to make it function. I hope this helps you!

Comment: @PythonMaster...thank you for your help, this is my first time use python, """"Create a python program called 8-queens.py that genereates a large number of 8-puzzle and 8-queens instances and solve them (where possible) using two of the following algorithms: regular hill climbing with steepest assent, random restart, genetic algorithms or simulated annealing. Measure the search cost (number of iterations until it hits a minima) and percentage of solved problems. """ this is what i have to do, do you think im on right track?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations
import random
import pprint
import timeit

start_time = timeit.default_timer()


def gird(board_size):

    print ("\n".join('# ' * inrange + 'Q ' + '# ' * (8-inrange-1)\
                     for inrange in board_size) + "\n\n= = \n")
coloms  = range(8)
for board_size in permutations(coloms):
    if 8 == len(set(board_size[inrange]+inrange for inrange in coloms)):
       8 == len(set(board_size[inrange]-inrange for inrange in coloms))
       gird(board_size)

       elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
       print(elapsed)
```

this will print all the solution and time of running of the code